# Mounting drives using keyboard shortcut

Tags: drive

Recently, I learned that we can assign and access specific folders using keyboard shortcut.  For example, to access my Downloads folder, I have assigned the command:

nautilus Downloads/

and a keyboard shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to access the Downloads folder.

Similarly, is it possible to assign keyboard shortcut to access folders located within unmounted drives?

For instance, I have a folder named "TTC Video High School Basic Math (compressed)"  located in /media/87daf597-b5fc-45e9-b961-30895d500bcc

but using

nautilus media/87daf597-b5fc-45e9-b961-30895d500bcc/

I am unable to mount the partition.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are not supposed to be any keyboard shortcut (in my opinion, so just ignore this).

About mounting, go on `nautilus` and click on a drive, or `mount /dev/sd(a,b,c or etc) destination-folder` should work too.